# Kalman Filter Pendulum Estimation State

Tags: simulink, kalman-filter, estimation, pendulum

I implemented an easy mathematical model of a pendulum on simulink. I implemented a Kalman filter to estimate the velocity state having as input a zero torque, the initial position set to a certain angle (pi/18) and the initial velocity set to zero.

I suppose to have just a position measurement as the output of the system and the goal is to have a good estimation of the states. I expect to obtain a good estimation of the angle and the velocity but, as far as the velocity estimation is concerned, it is totally wrong.

I think there is something wrong in the block diagram. The question is: it is possible to have a "good" estimation of both the state using a Kalman filter for a mechanical linear Pendulum?

Comment: Yes, a KF is able to estimate both states.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Phil. Try to design the Kalman filter with different Q and R. Also be sure that your simulink model has the same parameters as the Kalman filter.

Comment: And if I have two positions sensors, how should I change the matrix or the state-model to take in count to have multiple sensors?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to let the filter work as a estimator for both states. There was an error in the Model and it couldn' t estimate properly the second state